# How to handle noisy data?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have data (x,y) from eye tracker
I need to leave only the groups and leave the rest as the cursor in the circle

```
sw.WriteLine("X(pixel),Y(pixel),time_now,timer ");
var gazePointDataStream = host.Streams.CreateGazePointDataStream(Tobii.Interaction.Framework.GazePointDataMode.LightlyFiltered);
gazePointDataStream.GazePoint((x,y, _) =>
{
  if (enableGazeMouseControl)
  {
    moveCursor((int)x, (int)y);
    //update the form labels with gaze coordinate
    form.label3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => form.label3.Text = x.ToString()));
    form.label4.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => form.label4.Text = y.ToString()));
    sw.WriteLine(x + "," +y + ","+DateTime.Now+","+form.label5.Text); 
    Graphics g = form.CreateGraphics();
    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), (int)(x - 5), (int)(y - 5), 5, 5); // hama
  }
});
```

I need help

---

Comment: Unless you are looking for a library that would do it for you (which is offtopic), I don't see how it is related to C# or winforms. Generally, you figure out math that would help you achieve what you want and you implement it.

Comment: Note:  You're leaking memory. You have to dispose your graphic object because you created it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis